# Add PHP email validation to a variable styled code

Tags: php, email-validation

Simply, I found this code to validate email:

`filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)`

But unfortunately I don't know how to add this to my PHP code that get info from the form:

```
<?php $name = $_POST['name'];
    $email = $_POST['email'];
    $message = $_POST['message'];
    $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
    $recipient = "example@example.com";
    $subject = "Contact Form";
    $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
    mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
?>
```

I used Ajax to get form's submitted information.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `filter_input` function. This function will check if `email` argument has been sent in the `POST` request and if it has been, then it will validate it and return validated email or FALSE. Do it like this:

```
<?php 
    $email = filter_input( INPUT_POST, 'email', FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL );
    if ( $email ) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "example@example.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
    } else {
        die("Email is ivalid!")
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use it like this:

```
<?php
    if(filter_var($_POST['email'], FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
        $email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];
        $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
        $recipient = "example@example.com";
        $subject = "Contact Form";
        $mailheader = "From: $email \r\n";
        mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");

    } else {
        header("Location: your_form.html");

    }
```

If you're gonna insert this to a database it'll be good to sanitize your data with [mysql_real_escape_string](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php)

Also display a good message when the email is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php 

    //if the form has been submitted
    if ( isset($_POST['submit']) ) {
        $name = $_POST['name'];
        $user_email = $_POST['email'];
        $message = $_POST['message'];

        //if user's email is not empty and is valid, send mail
        if ( !empty($user_email) && filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL) ) {
            $formcontent="From: $name \n Message: $message";
            $recipient = $user_email;
            $subject = "Contact Form";
            $mailheader = "From: youremail@example.com \r\n";
            mail($recipient, $subject, $formcontent, $mailheader) or die("Error!");
        } else {
            //show error
            exit("Your email seems to be invalid.");
        }
    }

?>
```

Answer (score -1):

If what you need is a good PHP function that checks that the input is a valid email address, you can use this:

```
function validateEmail($email) {
$e = false;
if ((trim ( $email )) == "") {
    $e = true;
} elseif (strlen ( $email ) > 40) {
    $e = true;
} elseif (! ((strpos ( $email, "." ) > 0) && (strpos ( $email, "@" ) > 0)) || preg_match ( "/[^a-zA-Z0-9.@_-]/", $email )) {
    $e = true;
}
return !$e;
}
```

As you see it limits email length to 40 characters.

Comment: `what you need is a good PHP function that checks that the input is a valid email address,` -- that's **exactly** what `if(filter_var($email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL))` does.

Comment: @AmalMurali I'm happy to hear that Amal

Comment: Your function is much worse then `filter_var( $email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL )`, don't use your function and don't teach anybody to use it.

Comment: Take a look at [this article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/08/21/i-knew-how-to-validate-an-email-address-until-i.aspx) and then check what your function can validate.